# How to implement navigation in an WinUI3 application?

Tags: winui-3

I can't find how to implement navigation in an WinUI 3 application.

I want to be able to use the back arrow on the top left of the window.

When I try to get the rootFrame from a Page to navigate() to another page, or to goBack(), `Window.Current` gives a null ref.

```cs
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
```

I tried to implement it like in UWP.

In my Application class, I do my dependency injections and I activate my Window.

In my the xaml of my Window, I have defined a `NavigationView` width a back button `BackRequested="NavigationView_BackRequested"` and a Frame `<Frame x:Name="rootFrame"></Frame>`.

In the Window class I handle click on the back button.

```cs
private void NavigationView_BackRequested(NavigationView sender,
                                           NavigationViewBackRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        rootFrame.GoBack();
}
```

When I click on a menu item, I navigate to the right page `rootFrame.Navigate(navPageType)`.

From a page, it is not possible to navigate to another page as shown previously, because `Window.Current` is null.

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(CreateElemFormPage));
```

We can navigate like that :

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(CreateElemFormPage));
```

But it creates a new Frame and so prevent to goBack().

Comment: Windows.Current is always null for WinUI3. UWP apps have only one windows while WinUI3 can create new ones, so you can't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose your Frame (or Window) in the App class of the application:

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
     public Frame RootFrame { get; set; }
     ...
 }
```

Then you can set in your main window's constructor:

```
(Application.Current as App).RootFrame = rootFrame;
```

And you can then access it from wherever you like:

```
(Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(CreateElemFormPage));
```